# How to make chatbot using QnA data?

Tags: machine-learning, chatbot

I have a database of 46k+ questions and 150k+ answers. Now using this data I would like to build a chatbot. The chatbot will be able to provide small answers or provide links of possible answers.

What should be the approach for building these kind of chatbot?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend following steps:

1. Link questions with multiple answers, this link would be one small topic / chapter / state that bot can talk about.
2. Create desired conversation flow, meaning linking topics together in meaningful order. Link topics of same category together.
3. Have some kind of session that would store user variables. Depending on stored variables you could direct your conversation to different topics.
4. Define set of keywords that would be recognized as triggers to skip from one topic to another (to allow some conversation flexibility).

Remember that in Q&A communication bot is the one that should initiate conversation and offer set of possible starting options. For example:
"What can i help you with?" with possible answers (New order, cancel order, status... etc). Those predefined answers are in fact topics that user can enter.

Regarding technology... there is plenty, it depends what technologies you prefer and are familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. These guidelines are really helpful. It seems that preparing the data is the most challenging task.

Comment: Yes, I would say that most difficult job is to return right answer to user and for that data needs to be properly structured and formatted. But Q&A pattern is right place to start and if needed later you can progress to NLP and "open conversations".